# flex-column: how to limit the height of grow part so it does not expand?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm sure this kind of question was asked before, but I really can't describe it exactly and concisely enough to let the search engine to understand me. So here we go:

To better explain my question I'm writing the code in tailwind style here. A stack snippet is also attached below:

```html
<div class="root w-screen h-screen flex flex-col">
  <div class="header h-[72px] w-full bg-red shrink-0"></div>
  <div class="content grow">
    <!-- a whole lot of content, very tall, height > 2000 px -->
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I would like to limit the height of the entire `div.root` to `100vh`. However, because `div.content` is very tall, it expands the `body` that it shows a vertical scrollbar.

Well this is fairly easy to overcome, I only need to add `scroll-y-auto` to `div.content`. So the body scrollbar disappears, and `div.content` shows a vertical scrollbar. Perfect.

However later on, I decided to split `div.content` into two columns: both column shall have its own vertical scrollbar. Intuitively I changed the code to:

```html
<div class="root w-screen h-screen flex flex-col">
  <div class="header h-[72px] w-full bg-red shrink-0"></div>
  <div class="content grow">
    <div class="left overflow-y-auto">
        <!-- a whole lot of content, very tall, height > 2000 px -->
    </div>
    <div class="right overflow-y-auto">
        <!-- a whole lot of content, very tall, height > 2000 px -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this does not work at all, as the attached snippet demonstrates. `body` got its scrollbar back, but not `div.left` or `div.right`.

I've explored several ways to solve this problem. In the end the best solution I got was to set the height of `div.content` to `calc(100% - 72px)`. This works perfectly, but I understand it's only because I know the exact height of `div.header` is fixed at `72px`.

Was I doing something wrong here? What's the most elegant way to solve this kind of problem?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.very-tall-content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 2400px
}

.left, .right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 4px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <p class="very-tall-content"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p class="very-tall-content"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on Chrome. When the header-height is removed, and I add some content to it, it still stays on top and both content-panels have their own scroll-bars.

Comment: @niorad  it's because I left the `height: calc(100% - 72px);` workaround in the codepen. Now it's removed.

Comment: Please add a [example] as part of a stack snippet `<>` and not from a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, try this one maybe it fixed your problem :)

> instead of using  `flex` for `.root` use `grid`. down here we have a
> header with minimum height of 72px and if it's content overloads, the
> header will auto-fit them

```css
:root {
  --header-min-height: 72px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(var(--header-min-height), auto) 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-row: 1;
  background: darkcyan;
}

.content {
  grid-row: 2;
  display: flex;
  background-color: palegreen;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.white-space {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      Left Side
      <div class="white-space"></div>
      Left Side
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right Side
      <div class="white-space"></div>
      Right Side
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the example if it overloads.

> ```css
> :root {
>   --header-min-height: 72px;
> }
>
> body {
>   margin: 0;
> }
>
> .root {
>   display: grid;
>   grid-template-rows: minmax(var(--header-min-height), auto) 1fr;
>   height: 100vh;
> }
>
> .header {
>   grid-row: 1;
>   background: darkcyan;
> }
>
> .content {
>   grid-row: 2;
>   display: flex;
>   background-color: palegreen;
>   overflow-y: hidden;
> }
>
> .content>div {
>   flex-grow: 1;
>   overflow-y: auto;
> }
>
> .white-space {
>   height: 3000px;
> }
>
> .row {
>   display: flex;
>   flex-direction: row;
>   width: fit-content;
> }
>
> .item {
>   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
>   width: fit-content;
>   padding: 10px;
>   margin: 5px;
>   border-radius: 5px;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="root">
>   <div class="header">
>     <div class="row">
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="row">
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>     </div>
>     <div class="row">
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>       <div class="item">test</div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>   <div class="content">
>     <div class="left">
>       Left Side
>       <div class="white-space"></div>
>       Left Side
>     </div>
>     <div class="right">
>       Right Side
>       <div class="white-space"></div>
>       Right Side
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but it requires the knowledge of the exact height of `div.header` too - doable but not ideal. What if the height changes? What if it's dynamic/animated?

Comment: you're right, I updated the answer hope it helps you

Comment: Much appreciated! The use of `grid` is really interesting.